# Git lfs can't push angular project because files exceed file size of 100.00 mb

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm trying to push my entire local repository into my github repository. I have added the repo, committed the repo and added the remote repository. I have installed git lfs, checked that git lfs is installed, added git lfs tracks(see below) and added the .gitattribute. When I try to push the repo through gitbash I still get the following error:

```
$ git push -u origin main
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/{username}/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Enumerating objects: 2195, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2195/2195), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2177/2177), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2195/2195), 308.15 MiB | 109.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2195 (delta 260), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (260/260), done.
remote: warning: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/35e551783499373efd8f37ab5f2cf30081d207ca/4.pack is 54.39 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/4b90ebc77ad46c8187dd39ece1f934df6779c2c7/1.pack is 68.87 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/4b90ebc77ad46c8187dd39ece1f934df6779c2c7/14.pack is 78.10 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/fa9214961fba2fcc3fd6f2576fd07fb1f688a64e/0.pack is 80.18 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/2aa86d3e302d06a540894c9353d3e857f45ae6fe/1.pack is 54.41 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/2fb2dbbb412a1a3ffc842af340939ed15ae8319f/6.pack is 80.31 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: a66c432f3fd91922f522d4a48c5c75fa4666bc9a454592c6e5c2a4b90a43ab57
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/108df82e36d14c5cbf52cede86e23c14ff10c600/5.pack is 137.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/3759c7aedb3be007ae7758b97a55606e66f9aa5b/5.pack is 151.27 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/f9027151ddc69bc6b2be7ad182cc6b78434b351f/0.pack is 148.02 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/13982179bb9f378b179431598132bd35fa0f4a47/13.pack is 150.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/4540ee20ba8425d06b5e2c926f071f1d67056684/0.pack is 152.56 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:{github username}/{projectname}.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:{github username}/{projectname}.git'
```

I have tried the following git lfs track commands:

```
$ git lfs track "angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/*"

$ git lfs track "angular-project/src/.angular/cache/14.1.2/angular-webpack/**"

$ git lfs track "angular-project/*"

$ git lfs track "angular-project/**"

$ git lfs track "*.pack"
```

But nothing has resolved the problem. Am I using the wrong syntax? If anyone can help me resolve my problem please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain files and folders that are generated by the application during development and deployment. These should not be committed to your repo.

You need to add a `.gitignore` file at the root to exclude that content.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Updating with a link explaining how to remove these now ignored files from your local commit.

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-remove-committed-files-from-git-version-control-b6533b8f9044

Here's a sample file from the Angular project. You can see that `.angular/cache` is listed under Miscellaneous.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/aio/.gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# Compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc
/bazel-out
/src/generated

# Node
/node_modules
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# IDEs and editors
.idea/
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
.history/*

# Miscellaneous
/.angular/cache
/.firebase/
.sass-cache/
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
firebase-debug.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
protractor-results*.txt

# System files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: So would something like: *.pack inside the .gitignore prevent the files from being added and committed?

Comment: Use the linked file as your `.gitignore` and that will prevent the files from being added and committed. You may need to add items after the fact, but this one should hit the majority of known files and folders to ignore.

Comment: Added a link explaining how to un-commit files that will now be in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I added angular-webpack/ to the .gitignore file and  I was able to push the local repo to the remote repo. Thank You!